# Start new activity when phone rings

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'd like to start an activity every time the phone has an incoming call and, inside the activity, show some details about the number or accept / refuse the call.
The problem is that every time i receive a call the activity doesn't start.

Here is my code:

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends AriesMobileBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(!preferences.getBoolean(Preferences.CALL_SHOW_CUSTOMER_INFOS, false))
        return;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber){
            switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d(TAG, "IDLE");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d(TAG, "OFFHOOK");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d(TAG, "RINGING: " + incomingNumber);
                final Intent intent = new Intent(context, PhoneCallActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra(PhoneCallActivity.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, incomingNumber);

                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        long now = AriesUtils.currentTimeStamp();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                        now = AriesUtils.currentTimeStamp() - now;
                        Log.e(TAG, "ELAPSED TIME: " + now);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }.start();
                break;
            }
        } 
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

the activity (which, actualy, does nothing ):

```
public class PhoneCallActivity extends AriesMobileActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER = "phone_number";

private TextView tvPhoneCallContact;
private TextView tvPhoneCallNumber;
private TextView tvPhoneCallSystem;
private ImageView imgPhoneCallStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.e(TAG, "PHONE CALL ACTIVITY STARTED");

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    window.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_phone_call);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(!intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+39", "").replace(" ", "");
    CustomerContact[] contacts = new CustomerContact.Provider(context).findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

    if(contacts.length <= 0) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

}
```

and the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Answer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Refuse" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So my requests are:
1- how do i start the activity when the phone rings?
2- how do i manage the respond/refuse button?
3- if this solution is impossible/not good/stupid is there any other way to       show informations when a call is received? (for example some kind of notification)

thanks in advance

manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="ngs.ariesmobile"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

        <application
            android:name=".AriesMobileApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <receiver android:name=".receivers.PhoneCallReceiver" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <activity
                android:name=".view.LoginActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.HomeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SignatureCaptureActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SetupHomeActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SetupApiActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SetupLoginActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SetupTechnicianActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SettingsActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SettingsPasswordActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SettingsApiActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SynchronizationActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.ReportCustomerActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.ReportInternalActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.ReportListActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.TicketListActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.PhoneCallActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SystemActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SystemListActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.ReportSummaryActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity
                android:name=".view.ManualsListActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_manuals_list" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SystemStoricalActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_system_storical" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SystemTechnicalPartActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_system_technical_part" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SystemConsActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_system_cons" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SystemNoteActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_system_note" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.SystemSupervisionActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_system_supervision" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.CalendarActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_calendar" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".view.ReportHoursActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_report_hours" >
            </activity>
      <!---      <activity
                android:name="ngs.ariesmobile.view.ReportHoursActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_report_hours" > 
            </activity> -->
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Read following post http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/08/android-call-state-listener-example.html#.Vhe2j_mqpBc

Comment: what about your manifest?